# Why are there no simple atomic increment, decrement operations in CUDA?

Tags: cuda, increment, atomic

From the [CUDA Programming guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#atomic-functions):

> ```
> unsigned int atomicInc(unsigned int* address,
>                        unsigned int val);
> ```
>
> reads the 32-bit word `old` located at the address `address` in global or
>   shared memory, computes `((old >= val) ? 0 : (old+1))`, and stores the
>   result back to memory at the same address. These three operations are
>   performed in one atomic transaction. The function returns `old`.

This is nice and dandy. But where's

> ```
> unsigned int atomicInc(unsigned int* address);
> ```

which simply increments the value at `address` and returns the old value? And

> ```
> void atomicInc(unsigned int* address);
> ```

which simply increments the value at `address` and returns nothing?

*Note:* Of course I can 'roll my own' by wrapping the actual API call, but I would think the hardware has such a simpler operation, which could be cheaper.

Comment: Could you construct wrappers around `atomicInc`? For example, `unsigned int atomicInc2(unsigned int* address) { atomicInc(unsigned int* address,address[0]+1); }`?

Comment: @JackOLantern: See edit. Also, you mean `0` rather than `address[0]+1`.

Comment: Why not just use `atomicAdd`?  You've given no indication why that would not be acceptable.  There's nothing to wrap.  Furthermore, if you don't like the return value, don't use it.

Comment: This is a thinly disguised rant, not a constructive question. Vote to close.

Comment: @RobertCrovella: Make that an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: The title of this question is misleading. There *are* "simple atomic increment, decrement operations in Cuda" - you specifically describe one in the second paragraph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to accomplish "simple" atomic increment using:

```
__global__ void mykernel(int *value){
  int my_old_val = atomicAdd(value, 1);
}
```

Likewise if you don't care about the return value, this is perfectly acceptable:

```
__global__ void mykernel(int *value){
  atomicAdd(value, 1);
}
```

You can do atomic decrement similarly with:

```
  atomicSub(value, 1);
```

or even

```
  atomicAdd(value, -1);
```

[Here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#atomic-functions) is the section on atomics in the programming guide, which covers support by compute capability for the various functions and data types.

Answer (score 4):

They haven't implemented the simple increase and decrease operations because the operations wouldn't have better performance. Each machine code instruction in current architectures takes the same amount of space, which is 64 bits. In other words, there's room in the instruction for a full 32-bit immediate value and since they have atomic instructions that support adding a full 32-bit value, they have already spent the transistors.

I think that dedicated `inc` and `dec` instructions on old processors are now just artifacts from a time when transistors were much more expensive and the instruction cache was small, thereby making it worth the effort to code instructions into as few bits as possible. My guess is that, on new CPUs, the `inc` and `dec` instructions are implemented in terms of a more general addition function internally and are mostly there for backwards compatibility.

Comment: But it's not just coding the instructions, it's also returning the old value, and taking the time to compare `val` with `old` etc. I would assume a simple increment could be faster - or at least, that the API should not assume it isn't.

Comment: If you don't care about the value overflowing, you can use `atomicAdd`. It adds the immediate value instead of using it as a reset point. I'm sure the performance of the two is exactly the same though. They're probably implemented in terms of the same logic internally and the only reason they're not the same instruction is that there isn't room for two 32-bit immediate values in the instruction.

Comment: You could say that they should expose a more simple `atomicInc` instruction but that would only make sense if they though they would eventually implement that instruction on a future GPU, which seems very unlikely.